# How to get count of opponents via PHP in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking for a SQL statement, to get the count of opponents for every player listed in a table with match results. For example, in the table shown below, Esme played 4 matches against 3 different opponents. How can I get this?

| Player1 | Player2 |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | Bob |
| Christine | Daniel |
| Esme | Franz |
| Esme | Daniel |
| Daniel | Esme |
| Esme | Bob |

This is what I need as result:

| PlayerName | Opponents |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 1 |
| Bob | 2 |
| Christine | 1 |
| Daniel | 2 |
| Esme | 3 |
| Franz | 1 |

I already spent some days on finding a solution and tried several ways, but none gave me proper results. The last I was trying is "COUNT(DISTINCT Player1,Player2) AS opponents", but this gives a MySQL error. Btw, the example above is simplified to keep the focus on the problem. The real case is more complex, and I already have a working SQL statement using UNION, which gives me count of matches, sum of points and a rank. Now I want to add the count of opponents too. For any feedback on this many thanks in advance!

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward query using `GROUP BY` and a `DISTINCT` aggregate. As requested from the previous commenter, share what you’ve done and someone might be able to point you towards a solution 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to look at pairs in both directions and then aggregate:

```
select player1, count(distinct player2)
from ((select player1, player2 from t) union all
      (select player2, player1 from t)
     ) pp
group by player1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=962e2399bac2b5ad8144cbe862c4b742) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. I combined it with a Self Join to my existing SQL statement, which are two statements combined via UNION. Now my ranking system gives out the correct count of opponents. Many thanks, Gordon Linoff!